# Large image is not scrolling properly using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll

I have a multiple page jquery mobile app (along with Phonegap). In one of the dynamically loaded pages, I am trying to use iScroll (v5) to let the users scroll through a large image, both horizontally and vertically. Here is the code I am using for this page:

```
    !DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="largeimage-viewer" data-role="page" class="backdrop">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../common/iscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $("#largeimage-viewer").die('pageinit');
        $("#largeimage-viewer").live('pageinit', function (e)
        {
            var myscroll = new IScroll(document.getElementById('wrapper'),
            {
                scrollbars: true,
                scrollX: true
                //freeScroll: true,
                //fadeScrollbars: true
            });
            console.log("Created iScroll object: " + (myscroll != null));
        });
    </script>
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn-left top-btn" data-icon="back" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <center><a href='#' data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" style="margin-top:0;" onclick="$.mobile.changePage('appinfo.html', { transition: 'slide' })">CG</a></center>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" style="scrolling: scroll">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <img alt="Floor Plan" src="../common/images/floorplan.jpg" width="1217" height="1699" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->    

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I view the page on my Android (4.1.2), the image shows up but I can't scroll the image at all. There is no scrollbars visible either.

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing? Thanks.

Earlier, I tried the following without using iScroll library:

```
    <div data-role="content" style="scrolling: scroll">
        <div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: scroll;">
            <img alt="" src="../common/images/floorplan.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
```

This code showed the vertical scrollbar, and scrolling worked alright, but the horizontal scrolling was extremely slow and there was no scrollbar either. With all the swiping across the screen, I would get the image moved horizontally by one inch or so!! Any solution on this front would also be appreciated.